# How do I restore locked files from Trash?

Tags: pantheon-files, files

I was cleaning up some unneeded files in my Rails project when I accidentally deleted files that are VERY important to my project.

I realized my mistake and went to the Trash and found what I needed to get back. I right-clicked and picked "Restore from Trash". The file system crashed and I don't have any of my files back. I tried this maybe 50 times along with just clicking "Restore All". Same result, the window crashes every time. There is a tiny lock next to the folder I need and as far as I can tell every other folder.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

To open your Trash in [a window with superuser powers](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/8021/5565) in Loki, run

#### `sudo -i pantheon-files /home/$USER/.local/share/Trash/files/`

This command runs your files program (`pantheon-files`) as the root user (`sudo`) in the root's environment ([`-i`](https://askubuntu.com/q/70534/49899)) at the specified directory (your personal Trash folder). No need to change `$USER`, which will automatically translate to your current username.

From this window, you should be able to move your files as you please.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Files as administrator and restoring that way:

Open Applications

Right click on Files and click New window as Administrator

Try to restore/copy that way

or

In terminal

sudo mv /home/your_username/.local/share/Trash/your_file /your-restore/location

Comment: Thanks for answering: There was no open a new window as Admin option given and this is going to sound ridiculous but keep in mind I am not very experience with Linux, hence elementary os, I can't find the trash folder via the terminal.