# Run Pantheon Files as root

Tags: pantheon-files, root

All I want is to open my current window as root but all the hits are about adding contextual menu options. How can I open this folder as root just this once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Enter the following command in Terminal `io.elementary.files-pkexec`
2. In the old Files window, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to get your current path
3. In your new Files window, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, paste in the path you just copied, and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/02/open-as-root-elementary-os-freya/

It works for Loki and Freya.

Answer (score 0):

[This script](https://github.com/quassy/elementary-scripts/blob/master/enable-openasroot.sh#L5) works on elementary OS Loki to add "Open folder as root" option via `pkexec`.