# Restore original elementary OS theme

Tags: themes, settings

I installed some few themes, then wanted to restore the default theme. But when I restored from the tweak tool, I found that it gets broken or something and the status bar gets ugly transparent (photo below).

Please help me restore it as it was

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Go back](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/42p3b8/how_do_i_restore_elementarys_default_icons_themes/) to your install disk and copy over `/usr/share/themes` and `/usr/share/icons`, overwriting what you've changed (take a backup if you want)
2. Reinstall with `sudo apt-get --reinstall install`

Comment: you mean i should copy the folder from the cd that i install eos from it ? if yes  please tell me how to move the folder to the directory because if i did that manually it would say that i dont have permission and thank you

Comment: Yes, so if you are in command line, you use `sudo` to run the command as a superuser/root (top permissions). To open the graphical interface as root, [follow this answer](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/8020/5565).